# NA for Pearson Correlation in paired plots

Tags: r

I am trying to have a paired plot showing the Correlation Coefficients in the lower plot, but it doesn't give me the Correlation Coefficients for all of them. it only gives for one.

```
VehicleData <- read.table("VehicleData.txt", header=TRUE,sep="\t",quote="")
source(file = "VehicleData.txt")
MyNames <- c("Eng_Size", "NUMB_CYL", "Gears","Psgr_Vol")
pairs(VehicleData[,c(8, 9, 12, 20)],
lower.panel = panel.cor,
cex.labels=1.3,
labels=MyNames)
```

Comment: We will need a reproducible example to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely because you have missing data. You'll have to remove rows with missing data manually, or use `rcorr()` from the `Hmisc` package instead of `cor`.